# Sorting an array in linear time

Tags: time-complexity, sorting, counting, radix-sort

I need to find a method to sort an array in $O(n)$ time complexity.
I saw [this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-n-numbers-range-0-n2-1-linear-time/),
however I'm not sure how to apply it to the elements I need.

> *Input*: an array $A$ of length $n$, containing values from $1$ to $n^2$
>
> *Output*: a sorted array $A$

Can someone explain in pseudocode or in words how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a textbook application of radix sort.

Think of the inputs as 2-digit numbers in base $n$. Using a stable version of counting sort, sort the numbers first according to the least significant digit and then according to the most significant digits. Each pass takes $O(n)$, for a total running time of $O(n)$.

The same approach works for numbers up to $n^k$, and takes time $O(kn)$.

Comment: Why did you mentioned "stable version of counting sort" ?Counting sort is a stable sort by default?

Comment: I can imagine versions of counting sort that aren't stable, or indeed that may lose information. I'm not sure what the ISO standard version is like, though.